# Django Role Based Authentication based on Permission on URL instead of Permission on model class

Tags: django, authorization

I have studied abut Django Authorization. My observation is basically Django [Authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization) module works fine for Authorization based on role-based Authentication based on Permission on a Model instance. But In Spring framework I found [here](https://dzone.com/articles/securing-urls-using-springnbspsecurity) same role-based Authentication based on Permission on URL or actually relative URL or URL pattern here like .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRoles("USER", "ADMIN") in following code snippet. Here is a code snippet of Spring Framework:

````
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
        .authorizeRequests()
           .antMatchers("/static","/register").permitAll()
           .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRoles("USER", "ADMIN") // can pass multiple roles
           .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasIpAddress('123.123.123.123')") // pass SPEL using access method
           .anyRequest().authenticated()
           .and()
       .formLogin()
           .loginUrl("/login")
           .permitAll();
    }```
````

Is there any way or library in Django Similar way of Spring for Authorization based on Permission on URL? Thanks.